# Generating sample database data via Spring data.sql file

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I would like to initialize my postgres database with data.sql file. I have created queries like:

```
insert into network_hashrate (
   rep_date, hashrate
) 
select
   date_from - (s.a || ' hour')::interval,
   s.a::double precision
from generate_series(0, 9999, 1) AS s(a);
```

Is it even possible to populate database using postgres functions in Spring? If not, what are my other options. I need like 10k sample records.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc):

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and **initialize it (DML scripts)**. It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and **data.sql**, respectively.

So if you need to populate data only - just create `data.sql` file with your sql-scripts, place it to `resources` folder, then check `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in the `application.properties` to be set to `none`.

If you need more flexible solution, you can use [Flyway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup). To use it - add its dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Turn the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `validate`.

Add `spring.flyway.enabled=true` to `application.properties`.

Place you 'migration' sql scripts to the 'default' location `resources/db/migration` folder. Call them like this, for example:

```
V1__schema_initialization.sql
V2__data_population.sql
```

When your spring boot app will be starting, Flyway check your database for missing schema and data then rolls these scripts sequentially.

More info about Flyway is [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can run sql script after db scheme validate/created
Just name sql query file import.sql and spring should run it according this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

You need something that will keep a track of what query ran and when ran. Also it should only run once not all the time when application startups.

liquibase is a option which can be used for that.

It will allow DDL as well as DML.

This link will give detail, How can you configure liquibase with spring

https://medium.com/@harittweets/evolving-your-database-using-spring-boot-and-liquibase-844fcd7931da